# JavaScript: Function to display backside image of multiple tshirt colours

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple webpage that allows a user to pick a t-shirt and its colour. I want the code to—if possible—display the back image for every colour of tshirt with one statement, and in a second statement, be able to rotate it back to the front.

For example, something along the lines of this:

```
# = colour of tshirt

if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == # + "Front.jpg"){
    show_image(# + 'Back.jpg','back');   
}

if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == # + "Back.jpg"){
    show_image(# + 'Front.jpg','front');   
}
```

Is this possible, or should I just make one if-statement for each colour (back and front)? I'm sure there must be a better, more compact way.

Here's what I have so far: (Which only rotates one way)

```
function reverseTee() {

    var n = document.getElementById('shirt');
    var image;

    if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == "redFront.jpg"){
        show_image('redBack.jpg','back');   
    }

    if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == "blackFront.jpg"){
        show_image('blackBack.jpg','back');
    }

    if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == "whiteFront.jpg"){
        show_image('whiteBack.jpg','back');
    }

    if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == "lemonFront.jpg"){
        show_image('lemonBack.jpg','back');
    }

}
```

Comment: Would those voting down my question please leave a comment with how I can improve it?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with this question. It's clear and shows effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `for` loop would make the most sense here. Create an array of colors like so:

```
var shirts = ["red","black","white","lemon"];
```

Now if we look at your if statements, notice the only difference is the color?

```
function reverseTee() {

    var n = document.getElementById('shirt');
    var image;

    for(var i = 0; i < shirts.length; i++) {
        // If Front -> Back
        if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == shirts[i] + "Front.jpg") 
            show_image( shirts[i] + 'Back.jpg','back'); 
        // If Back -> Front
        if (n[n.selectedIndex].value == shirts[i] + "Back.jpg")
            show_image( shirts[i] + 'Front.jpg','back'); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, I think you could benefit from using the `switch`-statement. I have included a sample below. One key point to consider with your sample is that should more than one of the `if`-conditions evaluate to `true` - they all will be executed. If you decide to not use the `switch`-statement, you probably want to use the `if/else if/else`-structure in your function.

```
function reverseTee() {
    var n = document.getElementById('shirt');
    var selected = n[n.selectedIndex].value;
    var image;

    switch(selected) {
        case "redFront.jpg":
            show_image("redBack.jpg", "back");
            break;
        case "redBack.jpg":
            show_image("redFront.jpg", "front");
            break;
        //Add more cases here following the above pattern.
        default:
            //You don't have to have code here but you can. This will be called if none of the above cases match.
    }
}
```